# How to check if a file is compressed or not in Scala?

Tags: scala

Is there a way to find out if the input file is compressed ( ex: zip, tar.gz , .7z etc) in scala ?

checking for extensions is not an option because there could be many compressed file types and it is possible that the file could be simply renamed from .txt to .zip. We should be able to detect that its not a valid compressed file.

Regards

Comment: Check the extension

Comment: please check above edit We should be able to detect that its not a valid compressed file.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't seem to be very Scala specific question, but the best is to open the file, read first few bytes (i.e. *magic bytes*) and compare it with *well-known* signatures.

These signatures can be found for example [here](https://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html). An examples are

- 1F 8B 08 for .gz
- 42 5A 68 for .bz2
- BC AF 27 1C for .7z